# get specific parts of my file name as links

Tags: javascript, php, html

this is how i want my file name looks like : 55478_john_toyota_red.pdf
i have to file in a table of those informations
and this is how i get my file name for the moment :

```
echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
```

i want to know how can i get the number in an echo and name in another one ...as links to the same file.
my files will change all the time.

should i change the name of my file? can it be done like that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use explode function .. and then implode function to rebuild the file name like this:

```
$tempArray = explode('_', $file);
array_shift($tempArray);
$newFileName = implode(' ', $tempArray);
echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$newFileName.'</a>';
```

Try this version .. it should work now

Comment: it doesn't work (implode(): Invalid arguments passed ).i guess that this code will get me the first part how will i get the rest?

Answer (score 0):

it worked with this :

```html
$data = "$file";
list($numero,$nom,$marque,$couleur) = explode("_", $data);
echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$numero.'</a>';//in the same way i can get anything i want from the title
echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$nom.'</a>';
```